AddCors appSettings getting value problem
I'm trying to add origins in services.AddCors WithOrigins method, but I can't get origins from appSettings.
When I write url in Program.cs like this:
app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:1234").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
It works. But when I try to get url from appSettings, it doesn't work:
var x = appSettings.MyServiceSettings.Url; app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins(x).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
When I debug x, it has this value: "http://localhost:1234".
Why it is not working from variable / appSettings..?
I tried this example:
Use Cors based on an appSettings in .Net Core

Hi Guram, have you check this thread ?

Hi Jason, I've linked this page in my question. Exactly this is not working to me.

Here is the working sample for you, you can compare it with your code.

appsettings.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "corsAllowSpecific": [
    "https://localhost:7232",
    "http://localhost:5056"
  ],
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var corsAllowSpecific = builder.Configuration.GetSection("corsAllowSpecific").Get<string[]>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecific",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins(corsAllowSpecific)
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("AllowSpecific");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


Thanks for detailed help, yes, it works. But, in my case the problem was '/' character in the end of url in appSettings file: http://localhost:1234/ . When I removed '/', it started working :X
